# How to find coefficients for LinearRegression problem with Pipeline and GridSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm performing a LinearRegression model with a pipeline and GridSearchCV, I can not manage to make it to the coefficients that are calculated for each feature of X_train.

```py
mlr_gridsearchcv = Pipeline(steps =[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
('gridsearchcv_lr', GridSearchCV(TransformedTargetRegressor(regressor= LinearRegression(), 
func = np.log,inverse_func = np.exp), param_grid=parameter_lr, cv = nfolds, 
scoring = ('r2','neg_mean_absolute_error'), return_train_score = True, 
refit='neg_mean_absolute_error', n_jobs = -1))])

mlr_co2=mlr_gridsearchcv.fit(X_train,Y_train['co2e'])
```

I've tried to get best_estimator_ first:

```
mlr_co2.named_steps['gridsearchcv_lr'].cv_results_.best_estimator_
```

and I get:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'best_estimator_'
```

If I try this way:

```
mlr_co2.named_steps['gridsearchcv_lr'].best_estimator_.regressor.coef_
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: 'LinearRegression' object has no attribute 'coef_'
```

I tried other combinations but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```py
results['gridsearchcv'].best_estimator_.regressor_.coef_
```

where `results` is the fitted pipeline and `'gridsearchcv'` is the name of the grid search step in the pipeline, see the code below.

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.compose import TransformedTargetRegressor
np.random.seed(42)

# generate the data
X = np.random.lognormal(0, 1, (100, 3))
y = np.mean(X, axis=1) + np.random.normal(0, 0.1, 100)

# define the pipeline
preprocessor = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))

estimator = TransformedTargetRegressor(
    regressor=LinearRegression(),
    func=np.log,
    inverse_func=np.exp
)

gridsearchcv = GridSearchCV(
    estimator,
    param_grid={'regressor__fit_intercept': [True, False]},
    cv=5,
    scoring=('r2', 'neg_mean_absolute_error'),
    return_train_score=True,
    refit='neg_mean_absolute_error',
    n_jobs=-1
)

pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
    ('gridsearchcv', gridsearchcv)
])

# fit the pipeline
results = pipeline.fit(X, y)

# extract the estimated coefficients of the best model
results['gridsearchcv'].best_estimator_.regressor_.coef_
# [0.89791824 1.11311974 2.99750775]
```